# Samsung ML1915 USB printer not detected by cups

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, samsung, cups-lpd

My Samsung printer stopped working. I tried to remove it from installed devices, but I'm unable to add it again since it isn't detected anymore. The problem seems CUPS related since the printer seems detected normally. These are the outputs from some commands:

tail -f /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.808058] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using uhci_hcd
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.983104] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=3297
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.983115] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.983122] usb 3-2: Product: ML-191x 252x Series
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.983128] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.983134] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: Z2L9BKEZ600533N.
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu kernel: [ 862.990262] usblp 3-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 16 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x3297
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2"
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2
Feb 7 15:49:14 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: MFG:Samsung MDL:ML-191x 252x Series SERN:- serial:Z2L9BKEZ600533N.
Feb 7 15:49:15 piubuntu kernel: [ 864.032213] usblp0: removed
Feb 7 15:49:15 piubuntu kernel: [ 864.046284] usblp 3-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 16 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x3297
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: URI contains USB serial number
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://Samsung/ML-191x%20252x%20Series?serial=Z2L9BKEZ600533N.
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu kernel: [ 866.018157] audit: type=1400 audit(1454856557.291:128): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3606 comm="cups-deviced" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu kernel: [ 866.018179] audit: type=1400 audit(1454856557.291:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3606 comm="cups-deviced" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu kernel: [ 866.019187] audit: type=1400 audit(1454856557.291:130): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2084 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu kernel: [ 866.019205] audit: type=1400 audit(1454856557.291:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2084 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu udev-configure-printer: About to add queue for usb://Samsung/ML-191x%20252x%20Series?serial=Z2L9BKEZ600533N.
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu udev-add-printer: add_queue: URIs=['usb://Samsung/ML-191x%20252x%20Series?serial=Z2L9BKEZ600533N.']
Feb 7 15:49:17 piubuntu udev-add-printer: D-Bus method call failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.redhat.NewPrinterNotification was not provided by any .service files
Feb 7 15:49:20 piubuntu udev-add-printer: PPD: lsb/usr/cupsfilters/textonly.ppd; Status: 3
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 04e8:3297 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd ML-191x/ML-252x Laser Printer
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 08ff:2580 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2501 Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

lpinfo -v:

```
network http
network ipp14
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network https
network ipps
network socket
network smb
network ipp
network lpd
```

Many thanks in advance
Marco

Comment: According to https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/cleaning-up-obsolete-config-files-debian-ubuntu/, com.redhat.NewPrinterNotification is part of an obsolete package. It was probably renamed somewhere around Ubuntu 14.  I'm still digging...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug that I have reported at https://github.com/zdohnal/system-config-printer/issues/48.

You can download an updated version of some of the relevant packages from
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/1.5.7+20160812-0ubuntu1/+build/10606657.  (Download the .deb files, and install them using `sudo dpkg -i system-config-printer*.deb`).  However, upgrading didn't fix this for me, so I am waiting for a response to the bug report.